# What is the best current R-based big data setup?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services

I'm at that space between "medium" and "big" data.  I have # challenges:

- Efficient download / IO from server to local machine.

My data is stored on an Amazon Web Server, currently I download the entire dataset every day (changes represent <5%).

- Handle large datasets on single computer such that memory isn't an issue.

I want to have the same development experience on my laptop AND my deskop computer.  I've used RStudio's server appliation on AWS, but the application itself is somewhat slow and I prefer to use RStudio locally.

I'm not terribly limited by CPU power at this point, mostly just download / IO and memory.  What should I learn to make this process more efficient?

Comment: Are you using rsync for data transfer?  Does your "big data" problem fit in memory (or could it) or do you need an out-of-memory solution?

Comment: No, I hadn't heard of rsync, looks *very* useful.  I really need an out-of-memory solution.  I have two local developing machines, one has 32gbs and one has 8gbs of memory, it's becoming nearly impossible to develop on the smaller machine and I suspect that soon the 32gbs in the large machine won't be enough, either.

Comment: This kind of questions are very difficult to answer, as there's more personal preference involved than anything else. Plus, you don't give any specifications about either CPU or memory of your laptop/desktop, the operating system you work on and so forth. Last but not least, the problem you present is more related to bandwidth of your internet connection and download protocols than it is to programming. So maybe you have better luck on one of the sister sites, but for stackoverflow this question is alas not suited.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what your actual computations are, so it is hard to provide good advice, but for out-of-memory solutions, consider:

1. Splitting the problem explicitly into smaller problems (create files for each "chunk")
2. Streaming solutions--can data be handled a few rows at a time
3. For true out-of-memory work in R, the ff and BigMemory packages.
4. Parallel computing solutions such as the parallel package (does not directly address the memory issues)

Remember that out-of-memory solutions are likely to be quite a bit slower and requires more specialized work than in-memory solutions, so the first step is to buy more RAM, if possible, particularly since you are starting with small machines.  Machines with > 256G of RAM are not difficult to get these days.

For data transfer, definitely use an incremental solution such as rsync when possible and when it makes sense (small changes to dataset)--sounds like that matches your use case.